# Pandas resetting cumsum() based on a condition of another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a column called 'on' with a series of 0 and 1:

```
d1 = {'on': [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d1)
```

I want to create a new column called 'value' such that it do a cumulative count `cumsum()` only when the '1' of the 'on' column is on and recount from zero once the 'on' column shows zero.

I tried using a combination of `cumsum()` and `np.where` but I don't get what I want as follows:

```
df['value_try'] = df['on'].cumsum()
df['value_try'] = np.where(df['on'] == 0, 0, df['value_try'])
```

Attempt:

```
    on  value_try
0    0          0
1    0          0
2    0          0
3    1          1
4    1          2
5    1          3
6    0          0
7    0          0
8    1          4
9    1          5
10   0          0
```

What my desired output would be:

```
    on  value
0    0      0
1    0      0
2    0      0
3    1      1
4    1      2
5    1      3
6    0      0
7    0      0
8    1      1
9    1      2
10   0      0
```

Comment: Please assist us by providing these examples in code, not in images. If you have them as dataframes in a python session, just do `df.to_dict()` and share the results here. If you do so, I assure you you'll get an answer to your question.

Comment: We need a way to easily reproduce your issue, as @ibarrond suggests

Comment: I just edited the above codes

Comment: Perfect! You got a few valid answers in return :)

Comment: Read the [markdown formatting help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).  It will show you how to add code, data, images etc to questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set groups on consecutive 0 or 1 by checking whether the value of `on` is equal to that of previous row by [`.shift()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) and get group number by [`.Series.cumsum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html).  Then for each group use [`.Groupby.cumsum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumsum.html) to get the value within group.

```
g = df['on'].ne(df['on'].shift()).cumsum()
df['value'] = df.groupby(g).cumsum()
```

Result:

```
print(df)

    on  value
0    0      0
1    0      0
2    0      0
3    1      1
4    1      2
5    1      3
6    0      0
7    0      0
8    1      1
9    1      2
10   0      0
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us try `cumcount` + `cumsum`

```
df['out'] = df.groupby(df['on'].eq(0).cumsum()).cumcount()
Out[18]: 
0     0
1     0
2     0
3     1
4     2
5     3
6     0
7     0
8     1
9     2
10    0
dtype: int64
```